# Show that $x^2-7x+11.76$ has only one zero between $[2.5,4]$ and choose $x_0$ according to $|\alpha-x_0| < 1/M$

Tags: calculus, polynomials, solution-verification, numerical-calculus

> Show that $x^2-7x+11.76$ has only one zero between $[2.5,4]$ and
> choose $x_0$ according to $|\alpha-x_0| < 1/M.$

Showing that it only has one zero:

$$
f(2.5)f(4) < 0$$

There's at least one zero.

$$f'(x) = 2x-7 $$
There is a minimum between 2.5 and 4, and the concavity points downwards. This means that $f(2.5)$ happens before the function crosses the x line and $f(4)$ happens after the minimum, but still under the x line. Because it's a polynomial of 2nd degree it can only have 2 zeros. So only one zero must exist in this range.

Is this good? I never know what to say in these kinds of exercises because it's always intuitive. Is there a simpler way to do this?

2nd part:

$$[2.5,3] \\
M = \frac{3*2}{2*2.5*|f'(x)|} = \frac{6}{5|f'(x)|} \\
.5 < \frac{5\max_{[2.5,3]}|f'(x)|}{6} \Leftrightarrow .6 < .8333333...$$

Is this correct?

Comment: What are $x_0,\alpha,M$?

Comment: @ShubhamJohri it's the criteria for Newton's method